# Managing multiple/concurrent Insert & update requests in Flask-Restful

Tags: python, python-requests, flask-restful

I have used `requests` library to send json from a remote computer to a Flask-Restful API. The API inserts/updates the data into a database. I am using `uwsgi` with `Nginx` as reverse proxy

Everything is running fine, with no errors for a single client. I need  to implement this for about 3000 clients who would send continuous requests to the server.
If there are multiple clients,  do I need to store the requests( json data, about 500-600 KB), sent by the clients, on a file( for each client) until it has been inserted/updated.

Comment: I think not. 3k is a not very large.

Comment: @WaketZheng: Thanks for replying, sir. Would it run smoothly without any need of changing anything for that number of clients.